# Ошибка в синтаксисе при отправке запроса PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, pdo

Функция для соединений с БД

```
function db(){
  static $db = null;
  if(is_null($db)){
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPSWD, array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
    ));

    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $db->query('set names utf8');
  }
  return $db;
}
```

Отправляю так

```
$sql = "UPDATE `table` SET (`amount`, `signature`, `plan`) VALUES (:amount, :signature, :plan) WHERE inv_id = :inv_id";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':inv_id', $inv_id);
    $stmt->bindValue(':amount', $out_summ);
    $stmt->bindValue(':signature', $crc);
    $stmt->bindValue(':plan', $plan);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Ошибка

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`amount`, `signature`, `plan`) VALUES ('135', 'cdf15c5b50444f8ddde7c752261a5874' at line 1'

Comment: $out_summ = 135;

В бд: amount int(11)

Comment: а разве так строки [обновляют](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)? Разве не `update table set field1 = 'value', field2 = 'value'`?

Comment: Я влюбился в этот сайт, спасибо большое ВОРОН! Помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно было отправлять не так

```
$sql = "UPDATE `table` SET (`amount`, `signature`, `plan`) VALUES (:amount, :signature, :plan) WHERE inv_id = :inv_id";
```

А так

```
$sql = "UPDATE `table` SET amount = :amount, signature = :signature, plan = :plan  WHERE inv_id = :inv_id";
```